# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Freezing after Updating from 18.04 UPDATED

Tags: gnome, updates, freeze, clock

I have seen similar titles / problems such as mine on this site and I have tried their various solutions, but nothing has worked thus far.  My system freezes no matter I am doing probably ~ once or twice per hour. (even with all extensions turned off, shutter and variety also installed)

**NEWLY NOTICED SYMPTOMS:** The freezing seems somehow tied to my system clock/calendar.  Any time mozilla thunderbird/lightning alert from my calendar goes off, I can expect the system to freeze.  Additionally, in my panel, while all other extensions behave normally.  The clock and related calendar react very slowly and display errors when clicked.  Here are two relevant screenshots

Also of note `sudo lshw -c memory` (below) shows

```
*-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Intel Corporation
```

mozilla calendar (duplicates alerts messages for the same item 2 or more times):
[image]

gnome clock / calendar, note the distorted appearance and repeated entries
[image]

**Solutions that I have tried:**

```
1.) Booted to LiveCD and ran `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`  (no errors found)
2.) I installed and ran memtest. I ran `sudo memtester 1024 5` 3 times (no errors found)
3.) Checked ubuntu "Looking Glass" tool... (no errors found)
4.) verified all extension are compatible with current shell version
5.) I tried updating to the 5.9 kernel (did not solve the problem, reverted to 5.4 kernel, still using 20.04 LTS as potential upgrade to 20.10 seems unlikely to solve the problem)
```

**the details:**

**I am on an**

```
Machine :  Acer Aspire 5 (A5 515-55g).
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
Memory  : 7923MB (5740MB used)
Resolution  : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer : GeForce MX350/PCIe/SSE2 (Nvidia driver 455 open-source)
Gnome-shell version: 3.36.8
```

**Other Output:**

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

```
V1.08
```

`sudo lshw -c memory`

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Insyde Corp.
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.08
       date: 05/27/2020
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 4608KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 8
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 192KiB
       capacity: 192KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: ACR26D4S9S1KA-4
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: 968ADAED
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: 4ATF51264HZ-2G6E1
          vendor: Micron
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:6013108000-6013109fff memory:601310d000-601310dfff
```

`free -h`

```
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       5.4Gi       176Mi       801Mi       2.0Gi       1.1Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        41Mi       2.0Gi
```

`sysctl vm.swappiness`

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

`grep -i swap /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
total 80
drwxrwxr-x 20 user user 4096 Dec 23 23:02 .
drwx------  4 user user 4096 Dec 24 23:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:05 activityAppLauncher@rastersoft.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Dec 22 16:53 arrangeWindows@sun.wxg@gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:06 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:13 bitcoin-markets@ottoallmendinger.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Nov  4 13:32 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 Nov  4 10:00 drop-down-terminal@gs-extensions.zzrough.org
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:13 files-menu
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:08 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:08 netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:12 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:07 radio@hslbck.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Dec 23 23:02 simplenetspeed@biji.extension
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Oct 13 14:47 status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  7 user user 4096 Dec 22 16:24 timepp@zagortenay333
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:07 tweaks-system-menu@extensions.gnome-shell.fifi.org
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 Jan  9  2020 update-extensions@franglais125.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Dec 22 00:11 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Dec 22 09:41 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

`ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 19 13:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 21 23:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 21 23:20 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 21 23:23 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Any solutions on how to solve the freezing problem?

Comment: That is a remarkable amount of background information to work with. Thank you  — Based on your system information, you have a *really* new machine that would benefit from the newer Linux kernels, which better support your hardware. There are two options available: (1 — Easiest) Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10, which includes a newer kernel (2 — Moderately Nerve-Wracking) Upgrade the kernel of your 20.04 LTS installation to something equal to or greater than 5.8.

Comment: @Matigo  I aim to please (and fix my problem ;-).  I updated to the 5.9 kernel, same freezing issues, plus unsigned kernel issues that I didn't want to deal with, so I reverted back to default 5.4 kernel.  I updated my question above, because I think the unclaimed RAM memory is part of the problem. Check it out above