# What does "Memory unclaimed" mean in lshw output?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, firmware, ubuntu-drivers

I just did **fresh install** of Ubuntu 20.04 (completely overwrote previous install). Then installed all of the firmware / software updates.

Then I ran `sudo lshw -c memory`, which showed

```
*-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:6013108000-6013109fff memory:601310d000-601310dfff
```

`free -h`, outputs

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:          7.6Gi       1.6Gi       4.5Gi       124Mi       1.4Gi       5.5Gi

Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

**My machine**

```
Machine :  Acer Aspire 5 (A5 515-55g).
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
Memory  : 7923MB (5740MB used)
Resolution  : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer : GeForce MX350/PCIe/SSE2 (Nvidia driver 455 open-source)
Gnome-shell version: 3.36.8
```

Should I be worried about this?

Comment: Updated question... simply expecting a fresh install of ubuntu to install all necessary firmware / drivers...Don't think "UNCLAIMED RAM MEMORY is a happy state of being.

Comment: Read your output: Looks like you installed the wrong nvidia driver package. Uninstall it.

Comment: I didn't install anything.. the ubuntu installer did that...

Comment: I removed `libfprint-2-tod1`. It doesnt allow me to remove nvidia-driver-455.. says that is not installed and none of the fix broken packages commands work

Comment: Others with similar system, may give some hints? Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702
Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected

Comment: Are the memory used by your system? Please update the question with the ourput of `free -h`.

Comment: I see no problem at all. The memory is used.

Comment: @Pilot6  Are you saying that I should just ignore the UNLCAIMED RAM memory and the broken Nvidia-driver-455 package? straight question? LMK... I just had to do a fresh install because Ubuntu 20.04 was mystreiously freezing after an upgrade... (also showed unclaimed ram memory before fressh install).

Comment: You can ignore the unclaimed memory, the Nvidia issue if any is unrelated.

Comment: I also had an issue with entered data in applications not being saved properly... (ex. enter text in gnote, would disappear at random intervals) Hence that prompted to upgrade to 20.04.  Then after upgrade I had this mysteriously problem no one could solve.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302570/ubuntu-20-04-lts-freezing-after-updating-from-18-04-updated?noredirect=1#comment2214555_1302570   So I am worried about restoring my system with the current "errors" still present

Comment: I suggest asking another question about Nvidia. It looks like you are "fixing" your system without any reason.

Comment: @Pilot6 just an FYI, the mysterious issues that I had under 18.04 and 20.04 seemed to related to RAM.. (20.04 clock issues, 18.04 gnote/other apps deleting / not saving info)

Comment: So check the RAm with memtest. This is the only way to find out,

Comment: I have done that at least 20 times, never finds a problem.. That why I finally decided o na fresh install https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302570/ubuntu-20-04-lts-freezing-after-updating-from-18-04-updated?noredirect=1#comment2214555_1302570

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a new RAM controller that is not recognized properly by `lshw` yet.

It is not an issue at all, because all you RAM is working properly according to the `free` command.

Comment: I will take your advice and make a separate question about the nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

the list of repositories from which it gets the packages are stored here `/etc/apt/sources.list`

you can use the GUI to enable all the available repos under `Ubuntu Software` tab, enable all the repositories including `restricted` and `universe`

then try

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```